# how to dismiss mail view controller after tapping send or cancel button

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

while sending mail, after tapping send or cancel button view controller stays there and app stalls.

//swift 2.2 ; xcode 7.3.1 ;

```
  if( MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() ) {
            print("Can send email.")
        }

        var subjectText = "Verification"
        var toReceipients = ["notorious.roman@gmail.com"]


        // var msgBody = "Verified"


        var mc:MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mc.setSubject(subjectText)
        mc.setMessageBody("Verified", isHTML: false)

        mc.setToRecipients(toReceipients)
        self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {



        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `controller`, not `self`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think @rmaddy answer your question in his comment, nevertheless I going to explain you what's happening. You're trying to dismiss the `UIViewController` that presents the `MFMailComposeViewController` not the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

As [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/) specify in his documentation:

> The mail compose view controller is not dismissed automatically. When the user taps the buttons to send the email or cancel the interface, the mail compose view controller calls the `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` method of its delegate. Your implementation of that method must dismiss the view controller explicitly.

So you need to set the method in this way:

```
 func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4.0 Update.**
**Swift 5.0 Update.**

Allow me to add something to the discussion...

In Swift 4 and 5 the delegate method slightly changed; **As it's posted by you now, won't do any effect and won't get called.** It happened to me, drove me crazy!

The Xcode warning suggest three fixes but first two could be misleading. It's just a tiny fix...

Here's the delegate method fixed for Swift 3, 4 and 5:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Still, Victor's answer should be the correct/accepted one.

Enjoy!

Comment: It looks like the difference is the underbar in the function declaration.

Answer (score 4):

is had an Switch Statement that controls it for me:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    switch result.rawValue {
    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue :
        print("Cancelled")

    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue :
        print("Failed")

    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue :
        print("Saved")

    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue :
        print("Sent")



    default: break


    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```